# python2.7: generate random dates between dos values with specific format

Tags: python-2.7

I need to create random dates with the next format `2017-03-29 12:10+0200`, `2017-03-29 14:08-0400`. The generated dates must have to be between a start date and a final date.

How can I do this in Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by getting a timestamp as integer from each and then getting a random integer between these two integers you've found. Which is the timestamp in between, then you can convert that timestamp back to a datetime object again:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import datetime
from random import randint
import time

timestamp_one = time.mktime(parse("2017-03-29 12:10+0200").timetuple())
timestamp_two = time.mktime(parse("2017-03-29 14:08-0400").timetuple())
timestamp = randint(timestamp_one,timestamp_two)
result = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
print result
```

In python 3 you can also use the .timestamp() on the datetime object directly.